# What happens when Caffeine runs out of memory?

Tags: caffeine-cache

What happens when Caffeine runs out of memory during for example `put` operation? Is `OutOfMemoryError` exception thrown, or is the operation ignored? I could not find it stated explicitly in the documentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Caffeine won't catch `OutOfMemoryError` in order to suppress and evict entries. When that error is thrown the JVM is left in an unpredictable state, which may not be recoverable. It is best to use `-XX:+ExitOnOutOfMemoryError` and `-XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError` to restart and investigate the memory leak offline.

At first it might seem beneficial to defer all of the available memory to the caches and let the garbage collector evict when needed. This is the idea behind soft references. Unfortunately, that approach has been troublesome due to making full GCs more frequent and increasing their stop-the-world pause times. We instead recommend using an explicit maximum size, where the policy is quite intelligent. If you want large caches then usually a remote tier, like memcached or redis, is a good compliment so you get the speed of local access and a lower miss penalty on cache loads.